# Is it possible to create a child window in Processing?

Tags: user-interface, processing

I implemented a program to simulate flocking behaviour of birds in processing, however i would like to analyse the scale free behaviour of the simulation. For that reason i would need to plot a graph for the analysis. I don't have a problem plotting the graph. My problem is with getting the values i need from the simulation and using them as input for my graph which is a different Processing program all together.

Thank you for any ideas or thoughts.

Comment: Crossposted: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/whats-wrong-my-code/38761-possible-create-child-window-processing.html

Comment: Do you want 2 windows whit 2 different Processing sketches working at once?

Comment: Yes sort of, but not completely independent such that i can use the output of sketch A as input for sketch B. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Processing is just a Java library. You can embed a Processing sketch (or multiple sketches) inside a Java program, which is probably what you'd want to do here.

More info [here](http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/), or just try googling "Processing eclipse" or "embedding Processing sketch in Java".